# UISearchController results are not being filtered

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

So I am using the UISearchController in my project, and it seems to work all fine but whatever I type on the Search Bar no I get no results. So I believe the problem is on my
 **(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
}**. To be honest, I don't really know what code to put in that method. Here is the rest of the code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SearchResultsTableViewController *resultsTableController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults; // Filtered search results
// for state restoration
@property BOOL searchControllerWasActive;
@property BOOL searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder;

 _resultsTableController = [[SearchResultsTableViewController alloc] init];
_searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsTableController];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO; 
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; 
self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;  

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

// restore the searchController's active state
if (self.searchControllerWasActive) {
    self.searchController.active = self.searchControllerWasActive;
    _searchControllerWasActive = NO;

    if (self.searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder) {
        [self.searchController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
        _searchControllerSearchFieldWasFirstResponder = NO;
    }
}}

#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];}


#pragma mark - UISearchResultsUpdating

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to take the NSArray that your table view data comes from, filter it as per your search criteria, and then reload the table view. Your code might look something like this:

```
- (void) doSearch:(NSString *)searchText {
    [self.filteredClients removeAllObjects];

    if ( [searchText length] == 0 ) {
        [self.filteredClients addObjectsFromArray:self.users];
    } else {
        for (User *user in self.users) {
            NSString *name = [user fullName];
            NSRange range = [[name lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]];
            if ( range.location != NSNotFound )
                [self.filteredClients addObject:user];
        }
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if ( [searchText length] > 0 )
    {
        [self showCancelButton:YES];
    }
    else {
        [self showCancelButton:NO];
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
    [self doSearch:searchText];
}


- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self showCancelButton:YES];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    if ( [searchBar.text length] > 0 )  [self showCancelButton:YES];
    else                                [self showCancelButton:NO];
    [self doSearch:_searchBar.text];
}
```

Comment: Hey Larry I am not sure what you mean by User in the for condition??

Comment: NSString *searchText = searchController.searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *searchResults = [self.tableData mutableCopy];
    if ( [searchText length] == 0 ) {
        [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:self.tableData];
        
    } else {
        for (NSString *searchString in self.tableData) {
            NSString *name = [searchString self];
            NSRange range = [[name lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]];
            if ( range.location != NSNotFound )
                [self.searchResults addObject:searchString];}}
    [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: Sorry Sergio. I should have explained that my initial data comes from an NSArray of users (self.users here), each of which is a User class (basically an NSDictionary). I iterate over each user, compare their full name to the search text. If found, I add that entry to the self.filtered clients NSArray, which is used to populate my table view. Then I reload the table view. You will note that if there is no search text I all all users to self.filteredclients so the table view displays them all.

Comment: So for this is it essential to create a class? I mean in my project I just created an NSArray which would be my self.tableData, same as your NSArray of users.

Comment: No. My code has a class because it uses other things. I created a gist for you that might simplify this, using an NSArray and NSDictionary - https://gist.github.com/lborsato/d52ca5e286111f84fcf5.

Comment: Okay I get it now! Thank you, still my project crashes as soon as I type in a word on the search bar.. Don't know exactly what the problem might be

Comment: That could potentially happen if you set the delegate but the delegate did not contain those delegate methods. Just check the log and see why you crashed.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sergiorobles198/d35c6a40bc531860d242 - I created this gist with the actual project, everything is based on the Table Search code sample from Apple. I can't still seem to find the error on it. Im really having a hard time with this.

Comment: Where do you handle `- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)`? When your program crashes, what does it say in the log window? You should see a crash/stack dump with a reason.